# Filter between two arrays of objects avoiding nested for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, filtering

In Swift 4, how do you convert a nested for loop that is checking equality on only one property into a filter?

Basic Example:

```
// Basic object
struct Message {
    let id: String
    let content: String

    init(id: String, content: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
    }
}

// Array of objects
let local = [Message.init(id: "1234", content: "test1"), Message.init(id: "2345", content: "test2")]

// Array of objects, one has updated content
let server = [Message.init(id: "1234", content: "testDiff1"), Message.init(id: "3456", content: "test3")]

var foundList = [Message]()

// Nested loop to find based on one property matching
for i in local {
    for j in server {
        if i.id == j.id {
            foundList.append(i)
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected (foundList contains local[0]) but feeling there should be a 'swift-ier' way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for` loops can be rewritten with one `for` loop + `where` condition:

```
for m in local where server.contains(where: { $0.id == m.id }) {
    foundList.append(m)
}
```

or combine `filter` with `contains`:

```
foundList = local.filter { m in server.contains(where: { $0.id == m.id }) }
```

P.S. Also, conform `Message` struct to [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol. It allows you to simplify `contains` method:

```
for m in local where server.contains(m) {
    foundList.append(m)
}
```

using `filter`:

```
foundList = local.filter { server.contains($0) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Two explanations and Equatable protocal info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`.

```
import Foundation

struct Message: Equatable {
    let id: String
    let content: String
    static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

let local  = [ Message(id: "1234", content: "test1"),     Message(id: "2345", content: "test2") ]
let server = [ Message(id: "1234", content: "testDiff1"), Message(id: "3456", content: "test3") ]

let foundList = local.filter { server.contains($0) }

print(foundList) // prints [Message(id: "1234", content: "test1")]
```

Note that I removed the initialiser and I’m using Message(...) instead Message.init(...).

Comment: As JeremyP points out, this saves you from typing a nested loop, but it is still executing one.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to write a filter for this. I assume you want the local messages that are also on the server.

```
let m = local.filter 
{
    localMessage in 
    server.contains(where: { $0.id == localMessage.id })
}
```

If you have a lot of messages, it might be a good idea to create a set of interesting ids.

```
let filterIds = Set(server.map{ $0.id })
let m = local.filter { filterIds.contains($0) }
```

That will reduce the big O time complexity because you aren't doing a linear search through the set. The time complexity on `contains(where:)` for an array is going to be *O(n)* where n is the number of elements. For a set, [Apple documents the complexity of `contains()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains) as *O(1)* Of course, there is an overhead for creating the set and for small *n* the linear search might be quicker than the set access.

Comment: Hi, Jeremy. Could you share more info about `contains` complexity? Maybe link for docs or some article? Thanks.

Comment: @pacification no problem, I'll add to the answer